# Bundle not found when deploying to gcloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I'm deploying a rails app to Google Cloud App Engine. Since adding

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'foobar.appspot.com'}
```

to production.rb, the build fails on deploy. Here are the logs:

```
INFO[0108] RUN bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash 
INFO[0108] cmd: /bin/sh 
INFO[0108] args: [-c bundle install --deployment --without="development test" && rbenv rehash] 
/bin/sh: 1: bundle: not found
error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options, which you should to try:

1. Change `bundle` to `bundler`.
2. install `bundler` manually with something like `gem install bundler -v 1.17.1`